# Findbugs is generating different error count for different engines

Tags: java, findbugs

As per our code we need to use different building engines to build the code in teamcity.

but the main problem is the error count report generated for one engine is different from other engines. (1 Dodgy and 1 security errors are added extra)

For all the engines we are using **findbugs-3.0.1** for **jdk1.8 version**.

I am not able to understand why there is difference in the count when we changed the engine, though using the same **findbugs** version.

Can any one help me, is there any other factors that **findbugs tool depends**, which might be different in my engines.

Comment: It might depend on the generated bytecode?

Comment: if we use same java version, will the bytecode varies?

Comment: You were referring to 'build engines', maybe there are different command line options set? Maybe a different 'javac'?